# Neural ODEs-Dimension Mismatch in the proof of adjoint sensitivity method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, neural-networks

In the paper 'Neural Ordinary Differential Equations' (2019) by Ricky T. Q. Chen et al., it is noted that adjoint variable $\mathbf{a}(t)$ as the gradient of the loss function with respect to the hidden state: $\mathbf{a}(t)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$. Its dynamics are given by another ODE, which can be thought of as the instantaneous analog of the chain rule: $\frac{d\mathbf{a}(t)}{dt}=-\mathbf{a}(t)^\intercal\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$. Here, it can be seen that $\mathbf{a}(t)$ is a column vector.

The original proof in the paper uses row vectors, and if we wish to continue representing $\mathbf{a}(t)$ as a column vector, then we have
$$\mathbf{a}(t)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t+\varepsilon)}\frac{\partial\mathbf{z}(t+\varepsilon)}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}=\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\frac{\partial T_{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{z}(t),t)}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$$

And then

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{d\mathbf{a}(t)}{dt}
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)-\mathbf{a}(t)}{\varepsilon}=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left[\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\frac{\partial T_{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{z}(t),t)}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}\right]\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left[\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}\left(\mathbf{z}(t)+\varepsilon f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})+O(\varepsilon^2)\right)\right]\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left[\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\left(\mathbf{I}+\varepsilon\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}+O(\varepsilon^2)\right)\right]\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left[\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\left(\mathbf{I}+\varepsilon\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}+O(\varepsilon^2)\right)\right]\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left[-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\left(\varepsilon\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}+O(\varepsilon^2)\right)\right]\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\frac{\varepsilon\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}+O(\varepsilon^2)}{\varepsilon}=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0^+}-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\left(\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}+O(\varepsilon)\right)
\\&=-\mathbf{a}(t)^\intercal\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}
\end{aligned}$$

However, the middle terms $\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)-\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal$ cannot cancel each other out due to the different dimensions. If we want this equation to be valid, then initially it should be $\frac{d\mathbf{a}^\intercal(t)}{dt}$. But if so, this would lead to $\mathbf{a}^\intercal(t)=\mathbf{a}(t+\varepsilon)^\intercal\frac{\partial T_{\varepsilon}(\mathbf{z}(t),t)}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$. Therefore, it results in $\mathbf{a}^\intercal(t)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$. This contradicts the definition. Unless $\mathbf{a}(t)=\mathbf{a}^\intercal(t)$, is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you do not want to redefine all the notational conventions of multivariable calculus.
Then $\frac{∂L}{∂z(t)}$ is a Jacobi matrix. As $L$ is scalar and $z$ a vector, this Jacobian has a single row. So to define c column vector from it, you need to transpose it, that is, $a=\nabla_zL$ is indeed the gradient of $L$ rel. $z$.

This correction solves your format incompatibilities.

Comment: In the appendix of the original text, it is stated: 'For ease of notation, we denote vectors as row vectors, whereas the main text uses column vectors.' This implies that $\mathbf{a}(t)$ in the main text is used as a column vector. Thus, the text also writes: $-\mathbf{a}(t)^\intercal\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$. However, when defining $\mathbf{a}(t)$, it is done so as $\mathbf{a}(t)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$, suggesting that the result here is a column vector. Doesn't this seem contradictory?

Comment: I'm sure there will be other places where this is applied "wrong" to compensate for the format incompatibilities. In multivariate calculus, the gradient is a column vector or a vector of the primary vector space defined by $\langle \nabla f(x), v\rangle=df_x[v]$. In a more AD or ANN centered picture, the gradient is more seen as the quantities transported backwards through the algorithm of the function in question. Often it is left as row vector to more easily fit into the chain rule. So one has to look for the correct context.

Comment: In light of your explanation about the context-specific representation of gradients as either row or column vectors, how can I consistently use $\mathbf{a}(t)$ as either a row vector or a column vector to complete the proof process? Specifically, what modifications or considerations should I apply to ensure that the notation and calculations remain consistent throughout the proof?

Comment: There is no objectively better way. Some people prefer to force all linear maps into the matrix-times-vector format. Others prefer to leave the formulas as "natural" as possible, here with few if any transpositions. It is usually better to chose one "design principle" from the start and keep to it.

Comment: In fact, aside from the proof where the author uses $-\mathbf{a}(t)\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$, in all other places the text uses $-\mathbf{a}(t)^\intercal\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$. Why didn't the author write it as $-\mathbf{a}(t)\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{z}(t), t,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\mathbf{z}(t)}$ in the main text? This would eliminate the transpose symbol, making it appear more natural, and also avoid any issues of dimension mismatch.

Comment: From my understanding, either the transpose symbol should be used consistently throughout, or not used at all. Unless someone tells me that in the actual implementation of the code, $\mathbf{a}(t)$ undergoes a transpose, and during computation, it needs to be manually transposed back. I think having the transpose in some places and not in others only makes sense if this is the case.